# Oracle PL - SQL - "SQL command not properly ended" on an update statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've two update statements launched by an "Execute Immediate" function. One works ok but the other throws an *"SQL command not properly ended"* error.

**Statement working fine:**

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE myTable SET column_xpto = ' ||my_var|| ' WHERE myTable.name_table = '''||nameT||'''';
```

**Statement NOT working:**

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE myTable SET column_X = ' ||my_other_var|| ' WHERE myTable.name_table = '''||nameT||'''';
```

The variable 'my_var' is a NUMBER type while the variable 'my_other_var' is a timestamp(6), initializated with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

```
desc myTable 
Name             Null     Type          
---------------- -------- ------------- 
NAME_TABLE       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(200) 
column_xpto               NUMBER              
column_X                  TIMESTAMP(6)
```

Does anyone know why the second statement gives an error?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the SQL *after* variable substitution.

Comment: `... SET column_x = ''' ||my_other_var|| ''' ...` worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use like below

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE myTable SET column_X = ''' ||my_other_var|| ''' WHERE myTable.name_table = '''||nameT||'''';
```

since `timestamp` should be used as string literal.

You can either user bind variable also as Lalith said.

Comment: Better use bind variables.

Comment: Why? Whats the advantage?

Comment: The bind variable will supply the value to pre-compiled, it will supply the value to precompiled one, wherears in above is to be re-parse the statement again on runtime.

Answer (score 3):

I would use *bind* variables like one below, with `USING` keyword.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE myTable SET column_xpto = :my_other_var WHERE myTable.name_table = :nameT' 
        USING my_other_var, nameT;
```

Comment: I tried that, and it seems to work fine too. But what is the advantage? Beside the simplest sintaxe without all that commas LOL

Comment: @AdamBrave, apart from the SQL injection vulnerability, another reason to use bind variables instead of concatenation is treatment of NULLs for numeric values: if you use simple concatenation you'll get a syntax error at runtime, whereas with bind variables it will at least run without error.